# Type inference failing with method reference

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, method-reference

Since this is my first question, I hope this won't turn out to be a duplicate. :D The similar questions I've found tend to be about situations that are either pre Java 8 or where the missing type information is pretty obvious.

I've been playing around with a little library to make working with `java.util.function.*` interfaces, streams, and method references more convenient. Unfortunately, there are a couple of methods that look straightforward but cannot actually be used effectively because the type inference fails.

I should say up front that I know I can solve these issues manually by specifying types explicitly, but the idea is to avoid verbosity. So that does not count as a solution. The fact that things like type witnesses are needed is what is surprising.

One of the things I wish was possible is to use a method reference as though it were an instance of a functional interface. For example, something like `(Integer::parseInt).compose(String::toUpperCase)`. (Yes, a meaningless toy example.)

Well, why not create a method that can be called with a method reference and return an actual instance of a functional interface:

```
public static <T,R> Function<T,R> fun(Function<T,R> f) {
  return f;
}
```

That should also help disambiguate between different possible interfaces, since it forces the method reference to match a `Function` specifically (as opposed to maybe a `Consumer`).

But the verbosity required to use it makes that method pretty much useless, because the types (`T` and `R`) can never be inferred.

Here are some examples of what **does** work:

```
Function<String,Integer> f = fun(Integer::parseInt);
Function<String,String> g = fun(String::toUpperCase);
int i = f.compose(g).apply("123");

var f = fun((String s) -> Integer.parseInt(s));

int i = Fun.<String,Integer>fun(Integer::parseInt)
  .<String>compose(String::toUpperCase)
  .apply("123");
```

In the first three, the `fun` method is pointless, since we could just do `Function<String,Integer> f = Integer::parseInt`, etc. The last one is way too verbose to be useful.

Unfortunately, all of these fail:

```
var f = fun(Integer::parseInt);                         // :(
int i = fun(Integer::parseInt).apply("123");            // :(
int j = fun(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).apply("123");     // :(
Function<String,Integer> g = fun(Integer::parseInt)
  .compose(String::toUpperCase);                        // :(
```

To me it looks like the context that is used for inferring types is *extremely* limited. Is there a good reason for that?

In other words, since I'm not familiar with the technical details of the language specification, I'm wondering if there is some deep reason why these things could not be made to work as I would expect them to. Of course, it would also be cool if anyone happened to know of some nice (non-verbose) workaround.

(Btw, I've tried this in Java 15.)

Comment: "Is there a good reason for that?" The designers really don't want the implementation to be more complicated than it already is, I guess? But really, the "why" question can only be answered by one of the language designers.

Comment: It seems to me that it would not be very useful to support most of these examples. For the one with `var f = fun()`, I would think that the designers prefer to have more explicit types than hard-to-guess implicit types. The last one would work just fine with a lambda, so there does not seem to be a strong need to support it.